# Updating a table with CSV import - records to be destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

In my application, vendors upload inventory information for their store on a daily basis. I'm currently using find_or_initialize to handle changing inventory_item attributes (specifically price). My question is, how can I handle the case where products are discontinued? Obviously these need to be removed from the database, but is there a way to do that without having to destroy a stores inventory_item records and importing the new inventory CSV file?

Here's my current controller method:

```
def import
        InventoryItem.import(params[:file]), params[:store_id]
        redirect_to admin_index_path, notice: "Inventory Imported."
end
```

Here's my model method:

```
def self.import(file, store_id)

    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    inventory_item = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_code_and_store_id(row[2], store_id])
    inventory_item.update_attributes(:price => row.to_hash["price"])
        end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of thought, I figured out that timestamps might be a good way to handle this issue. By comparing the `updated_at` timestamp with `Time.now`, I can immediately destroy inventory items that are no longer offered by a respective store and are thus not updated in the csv import. If the store picks up the product line again, my model `import` method will just create a new record. Here is my solution:

```
class InventoryItemsController < ApplicationController

    def import
        InventoryItem.import(params[:file], params[:store_id])
        @store = Store.find_by_id(params[:store_id])
        @inventory_items = @store.inventory_items.where('updated_at < ?', Time.now - 1.minute)
        @inventory_items.destroy_all
        redirect_to vendors_dashboard_path, notice: "Inventory Imported."
    end
end
```

To make sure that records were always updated in the csv import (even if price didn't change for instance), I altered this line in my model import method:

```
inventory_item.update_attributes(:price => row.to_hash["price])
```

to this:

```
inventory_item.update_attributes(:price => row.to_hash["price"], :updated_at => "#{Time.now}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a boolean 'active' column to InventoryItem. Then the vendors can just enter true/false in their spreadsheets in a new column 'active'. During import you can update that attribute and just make sure the stores never show products that are not 'active'.

Comment: Hmmmm... the problem I see is that a store won't have the product in the CSV file if they don't have it in stock. I should specify that this needs to be done on my end - I don't want to add any burdens for vendors that might cause inventories to be inaccurate. The amount of data we're talking about here is significant.